# Mouse down event causes massive lag when I double click and hold down

Tags: android, flash, air

I'm making an android app, in which the character can fly (by fly I mean that the background moves, and not the character)

I have a button and an eventlistener that listens for MOUSE_DOWN, which sets a 'fly' boolean to true. Then i have an ENTER_FRAME listener that moves the 'world' down, when 'fly' is true. (I also have a MOUSE_UP event etc, but I don't think that's relevant)

This works as it should, but sometimes in the game it's required that the player shifts between flying and not flying rather quickly. 
Here's the problem: If I click two times quickly after each other, and hold down on the last click the game starts lagging. I can see on the button that it acts as if it's being pressed repeatedly. The lagging stops, when I release the button again.

Is this a well known phenomenon, and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I use Movieclips symbols instead of Button symbols, the game doesn't lag..